# Accessing worksheet methods from module

Tags: vba, excel

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want the user be shown a message that a specific worksheet has been changed and ask him to run a macro on that sheet manually. I can use the worksheet_change method like this

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox "Hey! Cell " & Target.Address(0, 0) & " just changed!", 
End Sub
```

Above code has to be in the worksheet module. I would like to know if there is a way to do this from my custom module, the reason being I have thousands of excel workbooks that need to be updated and I can easily replace the old module with updated one with another macro which I usually use to update the code in workbooks.

Comment: Why not calling the other macro (with vba function 'Call methodName') ?

Answer (score 3):

In your custom module, place this :

```
Public Sub My_Code_for_Changes(Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Hey! Cell " & Target.Address(0, 0) & " just changed!"
End Sub
```

In your sheets' modules, you'll only have to place this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    My_Code_for_Changes Target
End Sub
```

---

Or to handle all the sheets of the workbook (you can exclude some) :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "NameToExclude" Then Exit Sub
    My_Code_for_Changes Target, Sh
End Sub
```

With this :

```
Public Sub My_Code_for_Changes(Target As Range, Sh As Worksheet)
    MsgBox "Hey! Cell " & Target.Address(0, 0) & " in sheet " & Sh.Name & " just changed!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The problem for me still persist because, it is not possible to add the Worksheet_Change method in the worksheet module when updating the workbook with new code. I can only replace my custom module with updated one from another macro.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx , this will allow you to insert code directly in an existing module, for instance the second proposition `Workbook_SheetChange` in `ThisWorkbook` module!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an add-ins file as application-level event handler for this case
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213566

The advantage of this way:
- can use for every workbook that you open without copy any code again